# Bluetooth Low Energy - Connecting to same device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, integration-testing, bluez

I'm writing a Bluetooth Low Energy library. For now, it will only run on Linux (and with Bluez 5.41+).

I'd like to have tests that can be run on any computer with BLE support and test the entire stack (application, host and controller), *without* requiring extra hardware (another BLE-capable device). Requiring extra hardware is a great way of making sure the tests won't be run more than once in a blue moon.

For that end, I'd like to use my computer to connect to *itself* (as both a peripheral and central) during the tests. It *seems* like this should be possible, since I can be connected at the same time as peripheral and central to *other* devices. But advertisements from my own computer never show up on (my own computer's) BLE scans.

Is it all possible to have the computer connect to itself in this way?

Answer (score 2):

No, not if you only have one Bluetooth controller.
The reason is that radio peripherals can only transmit OR receive in a given time moment.